# Get button element of a submit form with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use [Ladda](http://msurguy.github.io/ladda-bootstrap/) (spinner on the button) on a submit button. The problem is that I don't know how to get the button element.

When I use it on a simple button (type='button'), I just send the event in my ng-click and do the following:
Jade:

```
button.btn.btn-primary.btn-xs.ladda-button(type='button', ng-click='accounting($event)', data-style="zoom-in", data-size="xs")
    span.ladda-label Accounting
```

Javascript:

```
$scope.accounting = function(event){
   event.preventDefault();
   var loader = Ladda.create(event.currentTarget);
   loader.start();
};
```

Here the current target is the button but in the case of a form, the current target has the form and all the inputs. The question is how to target only the corresponding button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, Ladda is for indicating a loading on the button.

I suggest you to use a custom directive on your submit button. Directive is where you manipulate the DOM in AngularJS. You shouldn't use the `accounting` function for this.

Here is the doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

You can but the directive `customladda` as an attribute of your submit button like this :

```
<input type="submit" customladda data-style="zoom-in" data-size="xs" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs ladda-button">
```

In Jade format :

```
input.btn.btn-primary.btn-xs.ladda-button(type='submit', customladda='customladda', data-style='zoom-in', data-size='xs')
```

And the directive code :

```
app.directive('customladda', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        var button = element[0];
        element.on('click', function(){
          var loader = Ladda.create(button);
          loader.start();
        });
      }
    };
});
```

Here is the plunker :
http://plnkr.co/edit/hixBizT13QHzHLsqWH2h?p=preview